# Javascript Split Method with Additive Persistence

Tags: javascript

This is my first Stack Overflow post, so please let me know if I am not formatting properly!

I am trying to answer this Coderbyte question:

"Using the JavaScript language, have the function AdditivePersistence(num) take the num parameter being passed which will always be a positive integer and return its additive persistence which is the number of times you must add the digits in num until you reach a single digit. For example: if num is 2718 then your program should return 2 because 2 + 7 + 1 + 8 = 18 and 1 + 8 = 9 and you stop at 9."

However, my solution keeps returning "str.split is not a function". I thought that was a standard method for converting strings into arrays. Any idea why this code might not work?

```
  function AdditivePersistence(num) { 

  let str = num.toString; //number into string
  let arr = str.split(""); //string into array


  // adds numbers in array, then repeats until left with single digit
  let count = 0;
  while(arr.length > 1) {
    arr.reduce(function(a,b){ return Number(a) + Number(b) });
    count++;
  }

  return count; 

  };
```

I tried searching Stack Overflow, Google, W3Schools, MDN and other Coderbyte answers but could not figure out why this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: People are suggesting alternatives, the problem with your code is you're not calling the toString() method, you're missing the parentheses.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Ah, that explains why it wasn't converting to a string. Thanks so much for pointing that out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `String()` constructor.

```
let str = String(num);
```

Note also, `while` loop does not conclude as `arr` is not redefined by call to `.reduce()`. You can redefine `arr` by using `String()` constructor and `.split()` again within `while` loop

```js
  function AdditivePersistence(num) {

    let str = String(num); //number into string
    let arr = str.split(""); //string into array
    // adds numbers in array, then repeats until left with single digit
    let count = 0;
    while (arr.length > 1) {
      // set `arr` to string then array with values returned from `.reduce()`
      arr = String(arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return Number(a) + Number(b)
      })).split("");
      count++;
    }

    return count;

  };

var n = AdditivePersistence(2718);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the while loop issue! It makes sense now. The reduce method outputs a number, NOT an array, so we convert the reduced value to a string with the String() constructor and THEN turn it back into an array with split. This actually changes the array length so we don't get an infinite loop. Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to string this way:

```
let str = num + '';
```

Comment: Interesting hack. Thanks for the feedback!